# Is the limit of the "tent functions" continious on $[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis

Im studied this question and answer,

[Convergence of tent function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62518/convergence-of-tent-function).

And asked myself the following question, is the limit of these functions continous?

we are dealing with $0 \times \infty$ for the limit function on a point set. In sup norm we cant neglect zero sets and so we must think that $0 \times \infty=0$

What is the conventional way of reasiong here?

It looks like the modulus of continuity is $1$ and so it cant be continous since having this $0$ is nessesary and sufficent in this space.

Comment: Before asking this you should know who this limit is.

Comment: @Crostul well I dont "know" what the limit is, I think its zero and would like to know but I think I have some contradictory results. Unless we consider $\infty \times 0$ to be $0$

Comment: I don't see any $\infty \times 0$ . Where do you see it?

Comment: @Crostul The value at zero of the limit function

Comment: Well, for all $n$ you have $x_n(0)=0$. So $$\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n(0)= \lim_{n \to \infty} 0= 0$$ No $\infty \times 0$, it's just the limit of a constant sequence.

Comment: @Crostul wanna copy that to an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for all $n$ you have $x_n(0)=0$. So $$\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n(0)= \lim_{n \to \infty} 0= 0$$ No $\infty \times 0$, it's just the limit of a constant sequence $0$.

Comment: The confusion were weather how the limit function is suppose to be evaluated I guess. But since a function is determined by its values we can do it pointwise directly instead of after the limit is taken. Right?

Comment: Yes: if you want the pointwise limit, you have to compute the limit pointwise. However, these functions do not converge uniformly.

Comment: Right, and my question was weather the limit was continous but that has nothing to do with converge per say. 

For some reason I was thinking that the functions needed to convergce in the norm on the space inorder to be  in the space but ofc this has nothing to do with it. Not in this situation anyway.